# TinyMCE Force newline \n after shorcode tags in editor visual mode

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In the function below, I've added a "\n" string at the end of the column 1 shortcode, however it has no effect in the tinyMCE visual editor. I'm expecting a newline to separate the shortcodes onto their own line *(while editing only, I'm not referring to the processed shortcode on the live site)*.

How can I force it without adding an actual html `<br>` or `<p>` tag there?

```
function tinyMCEshortcode() {

    var tagtext;

    var customid = getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('customstyle'));

        if (customid != 0 ){
            tagtext = "["+ customid + "]Insert Your Text Here[/" + customid + "]";
        }
        if (customid != 0 && customid == 'two_columns' ){
            tagtext = "["+ customid + "_1]<p>Content 1 Here</p>[/" + customid + "_1]" + "\n";
            tagtext += "["+ customid + "_2]<p>Content 2 Here</p>[/" + customid + "_2]";
        }

    if(window.tinyMCE) {
        window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('content', 'mceInsertContent', false, '<p>'+tagtext+'</p>');

        //Peforms a clean up of the current editor HTML.
        //tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceCleanup');
        //Repaints the editor. Sometimes the browser has graphic glitches.
        tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceRepaint');
        tinyMCEPopup.close();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Great question that is troubling me too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't have any visual effect due to the fact that tinyMCE content is in HTML.
This has the same effect as if you would edit a page of your webpage and insert "\n" somewhere there. HTML ignores this, you would need to insert a `<br>`-tag - there is no other way.